# Python Script gets ORA-03150 but same procedure runs fine from sqldeveloper

Tags: python, oracle

My Python Script fails while running a stored procedure that accesses a view that uses a DB link to access a remote table.

That stored procedure works fine when run from Oracle SQL Developer but not when run from the python script.

When run from SQL Developer the stored procedure takes about a minute to run but fails in the python script after about 16 minutes.

It throws this error:

> ORA-03150: end-of-file on communication channel for database link

Why would it fail from python and not sql developer?  Why is it slower in python?  It is logging in with the same userid in both.

Comment: please show a [mcve]

Comment: That is a generic error: it could be anything. You need to get the full error stack. Have you looked in the alert log for more details?